# MQTT how the Client know internet is disconnected javascript

Tags: javascript, mqtt

we have a problem in our project i am not getting any response if internet is disconnected. So how to know client internet is disconnected in MQTT protocol.I want to return a message if internet is disconnected.

Comment: Which js mqtt library?

Comment: i am using meteor.js

Comment: Meteor is not an mqtt library